# Split a column into two values in R

Tags: r, variables, split

I want to split a dataframe containing only 1 column with below values into two columns containing only the numeric values

```
1: [0.426321243245,0.573678756755]
2: [0.413189679382,0.586810320618]
```

I have tried different ways in R using dplr -starts_with,seperate etc but couldn't split the column into dataframe containing two seperate columns.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
newdf <- read.table(text = "column1
0.426321243245,0.573678756755
0.413189679382,0.586810320618
", header = T)


library(splitstackshape)
final <- cSplit(newdf, 'column1', sep=",", type.convert=FALSE)
```

Comment: You're answer works but how to remove the square brackets. i don't need those!

Comment: Below line worked for me. 
Thanks!

df_1 <-read.table(text=gsub('\\[|\\]',' ',df_final$V1),sep=",", col.names=c('No', 'Yes'))

Comment: your welcome, you can use gsub or str_replace_all